Position of Windows 11 VPN (L2TP) login dialog, activated from tray/network widget?
I have a regular Windows 11 L2TP VPN connection, for which I don't store credentials so I type them in on every connect. I prefer to connect the VPN from the tray widget, and it does open the login dialog.
The problem is that since a couple of weeks back the dialog shows up at the top left corner of the screen, instead of in the vicinity of the tray widget (lower right).
Not a big problem of course, but it is a bit of a nuisance to have to move the mouse across the screen, especially since the dialog doesn't automatically receive input focus.
Any idea why this started happening? Any idea how I can move the dialog or otherwise streamline this somewhat frequent operation?
